# php: How to rotate a phrase in a PDF

Tags: php, pdf

I have to print a pdf file with some results but there is a specific phrase that I want to rotate it 180°

```
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 10);
$pdf->SetXY($x, $y );
$pdf->Cell(40,10, $result);
```

Is there a specific function to rotate the result or I have to play with the x and y attributes?

Comment: This question is related to some specific library of PDF manipulation, Please specify which PDF Library you are using actually ?

Comment: FPDF                                                              Version: 1.7

Comment: there is no rotate function function in this library

Comment: If you checked out http://fpdf.de/downloads/addons/2

Comment: yes this works fine with an image or a text but I have some case where the result is bar code how can I rotate this, is there a function that can rotate a part(text, image, bar code..)in the pdf once?